# iconv equvalent of mb_string functions

Tags: php, iconv

I have the next sequence of code:

```
// characters U-00000080 - U-000007FF, mask 110XXXXX
$char= pack('C*', $ord_v, ord($string{$c + 1}));
$c += 1;
$utf16= mb_convert_encoding($char, 'UTF-16', 'UTF-8');
$ret .= sprintf('\u%04s', bin2hex($utf16));
```

The code is part of json encode function from json.org.
  What is the equivalent iconv conversion to achive the same thing?
  I tried iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-16', $char); but iconv inserts a LE flag byte (I guess), and I don't know how to deal with it.

Regards,
Alex

Answer (score 0):

`iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-16', '$char')` converts the string "$char". To convert the content of the variable `$char` omit the apostrophes. `iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-16', $char)`

Comment: sorry for the miss-typed question. in the original code I omitted the quotes.